# forecasting grouped data r

Tags: r, forecasting

My data has Accounts, Month and the Amount with respect to the Accounts and Month. I need to do a forecast of Amount for the next 3 months for each Account.
Can someone please suggest how this can be achieved.?

Comment: What have you done till now? Give us a snapshot of the dataset

Comment: my data has AccountId, MonthNumber and Amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sweep` package that can be nicely used with `tidyverse`, see the vignette with the relevant example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW01_Forecasting_Time_Series_Groups.html).

For the future, though, make sure you provide a reproducible (dummy) example of your data with the exact description what you're trying to achieve.